# Parse JS array in JSON string as Golang map

Tags: arrays, json, go

An API I query returns a JSON where one of the elements should be an array but is wrapped in quotation marks. It seems therefore the "encoding/json" package doesn´t recognize that element as an array.

When I try to make that element accessible as a map I get the error:

```
interface conversion: interface is string, not []interface {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/K1H01q-Dqc

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

var incomingJson string = `{
    "status":"success",
    "content":"[{\"id\":\"567670128\"},{\"id\":\"567670129\"}]"
    }`

func main() {

    // Decode incoming json
    var encodedJson map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(incomingJson), &encodedJson)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(encodedJson)

    // Accessing "content" data
    contentOjects := encodedJson["content"].([]interface{})
    contentObject0 := contentOjects[0].(map[string]string)
    fmt.Println(contentObject0)
}
```

How should I convert/cast the string in `["content"]` so I can parse it into `map[string]string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `"content"` is a JSON string which by the way is another JSON encoded text. So if this is what you get, you may unmarshal the value of `"content"` just like you unmarshal any other JSON text:

```
var contentOjects []interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(encodedJson["content"].(string)), &contentOjects)
check(err)
contentObject0 := contentOjects[0].(map[string]interface{})
fmt.Println(contentObject0)
```

Output:

```
map[id:567670128]
```

Alternatively you may unmarshal right into a value of type `[]map[string]interface{}` (or even `[]map[string]string` if you know it only contains `string` values):

```
// Accessing "content" data
var contentOjects2 []map[string]interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(encodedJson["content"].(string)), &contentOjects2)
check(err)
fmt.Println(contentOjects2[0])
```

Output is the same:

```
map[id:567670128]
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tTIMkzYRwu).